# js object push using a variable key

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build a json object and I want to specify the key using a variable (testName). When I JSON.stringify the logger object it showing testName instead of the what the variable value actually is. log is a variable and that one shows just fine. It is just the key testName which is not showing the value of the variable. Thanks

```
logger.push({
  testName: {
    logs: log,
    screenshots: ''
  }
});
```

Comment: You can't do that with an object literal. Create an empty object and then set the property with the `[]` operator.

Comment: In ES6, you could say `[testName]: {...`.